# Releasing a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

NB: To clarify what I'm trying to do here:

I have an instance of a subclass of UIView. When this instance gets released from a View Controller I would like that the dealloc method of that instance be called.

The point being to release other objects within that instance of the subclass of UIView.

In the View Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mav = [[MapAreaView alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mav];
    [self.mav release];

    t_ = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 20.0f target: self selector:@selector(onTick) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
}
```

and:

```
- (void)onTick
{
    NSLog(@"Releasing...");
    [t_ invalidate];
    t_ = nil;
    [self.mav release];
    [self.mav release];
    [self.mav release];
    NSLog(@"Done releasing.");
}
```

In MapAreaView:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"map view area dealloc called.");
    [super dealloc];
}
```

**I am trying to release the MapAreaView and have it's dealloc method called.**

Also, when I run this app, `Releasing...` and `Done releasing.` get printed, but not `map view area dealloc called`. And despite all of my excessive release messages sent to self.mav the app doesn't crash. Weird.

Ideas?

**EDIT 1**

```
@interface MemoryManagmentViewController : UIViewController {

    MapAreaView *mav_;
    NSTimer *t_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MapAreaView *mav;
```

which is then synthesized: `@synthesize mav = mav_;`

**EDIT 2**

Please not that the timer is not for use in my real application. I'm just using it to learn about memory management.

Comment: in your viewDidLoad, you already released the self.mav

Comment: Calling `release` n times doesn't assume that `dealloc` will be called. `dealloc` called when ref count == 0. Check your another references for this view.

Comment: @tonio.mg Please see Edit 1. @kv0 I thought that when the ref count == 0 the object gets released and when an a object gets released that is when `dealloc` gets called, no?

Comment: Dealloc on the viewcontroler is called if the controller is destroyed (no ref anymore from other objects). Load / unload (view) does not trigger dealloc.

Comment: @hburde Not sure if you've read correctly. The `dealloc` that I'm looking to get called is in MapAreaView which is a subclass of UIView, not a View Controller. Also, nothing is getting loaded or unloaded here. I'm looking to trigger the dealloc method of the MapAreaView object by sending it the release message.

Comment: Why do you care about when -dealloc is called? It'll be called when it needs to be called. Don't try to force the issue.

Comment: @Caleb Please see my NB up top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't use `[self.mav release]`. This is incorrect use of properties, and is not guaranteed to release your object. Use `self.mav = nil` instead.

Secondly, I presume your crazy timer is there just to try and force the release of your view and isn't really code you are using? Because it really shouldn't be there!

To manage the memory of a view that you want to both keep a pointer to and add as a subview to your main view, remove the release and timer messages from your viewDidLoad. You now have one retained pointer to `mav`, via your property, and the view will be retaining it as well since it is a subview.

In viewDidUnload, your view no longer exists so it will no longer have a pointer to `mav`. Therefore, if you put `self.mav = nil` there, `mav` will be released.

You shouldnt try to release it while it is still a subview of another view.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to integrate this into my code. Will this trigger the dealloc method?

Comment: Only when your view controller's view is unloaded, which you don't really have control over. If you just want to run dealloc, don't add the view as a subview- just create it, then set the property to nil.

Answer (score 2):

**You don't get to choose when `dealloc` gets run***

You don't know what else in the iOS framework is retaining your map view.

You should think about memory management in terms of ownership - while you want an object, make sure you've `retained` it (either explicitly or as a property) and when you are finished with it, make sure you release it (etiher by calling `release`, `autorelease` or by setting your property to `nil`).

Your map view will get released eventually, don't try to force it!

(And it's been said in many other answers but it pretty important so here it is again - don't call `self.property release`, do `self.property = nil;` instead :)

*not entirely true for object in libraries you have written yourself but it's definitely true for objects from third party frameworks, including ones from Apple!

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.mav];
```

will retain `self.mav` and should be paired by this line in `onTick`.

```
[self.mav removeFromSuperview];
```

I'm not sure why your over-releasing in `onTick` doesn't release `self.mav` anyway - but if you do weird stuff you can guarantee that weird stuff will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't release it within `onTick` again. Do these two steps:

```
[self.mavview removeFromSuperView];
self.mavview = nil;
```

That's it. There won't be any more references, so it will be deallocated.

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost thing is
NEVER call release on self.iVar

Donot user self.iVar while allocating.

These are the basic things in memory management.